# Stata - Generating rolling average variable

Tags: stata, moving-average, weighted-average

I'd like to generate a rolling average variable from a basketball dataset. So if the first observation is 25 points on January 1, the generated variable will show 25. If the second observation is 30 points on January 2, the variable generated will show 27.5. If the third observation is 35 points, the variable generated will show 30, etc.

Comment: yeah i already tried that to no avail, i was hoping for an egen command or gen command

Comment: So show us exactly what you typed,  what Stata responded, and what the problem is.

Comment: You should not post questions without code. If you solve a problem yourself you should post a solution. I've posted a solution to give this thread some value.

Answer (score 3):

For variable `y` ordered by some time `t` at its simplest the average of values to date is

```
gen yave = sum(y) / _n
```

which is the cumulative sum divided by the number of observations. If there are occasional missing values, they are ignored by `sum()` but the denominator needs to be fixed, say

```
 gen yave = sum(y) / sum(y < .)
```

This generalises easily to panel structure

```
 bysort id (t) : gen yave = sum(y) / sum(y < .)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with. I had to create three variables, a cumulative point total (numerator) and a running count (denominator), then divided the two variables to get player points per game:

```
gen player_pts = points if player[_n]!=player[_n-1]
replace player_pts=points+player_pts[_n-1] if player[_n]==player[_n-1]&[_n]!=1
by player: gen player_games= [_n]
gen ppg=player_pts/player_games
```

Comment: This is correct so long as there are no missing values. Note that creating a new variable for the count is not necessary.